# Custom ProgressBar With Multi Color

Tags: android, progress-bar, customization

My Application requirement is custom progressbar.A Custom Progress Which have Multicolor Indication.For example Progress Smaller than 30 shown with Green Color .Progress Smaller than 60 and Greater than 30 shown with yellow color and finally the Progress From 60 to 100 Shown with Red Color .

i would like to make progress bar like this

http://www.android2freeware.com/Application/34/2011-08/10906.html#.TlTvqmEmsg_

I am new to android development.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Cool! And what's your question?

Comment: My Question is How can i accomplish this.i mean what should be my starting point. Regards

Comment: My Required ProgressBar Behiever should be Like That http://www.android2freeware.com/Application/34/2011-08/10906.html#.TlTvqmEmsg_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the `Seekbar` class and override its `onDraw()` method. There you can draw the thumb and progress background however you want.

Create a drawable progress background statically (easier than drawing in program.) and add to resources. You can set this as progress drawable in xml or in your custom class constructor.

```
class MySeekbar extends Seekbar {

    // In Constructor load the thumb image into static members.

    // override onDraw draw the thumb.
    void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         canvas.save();
         canvas.drawBitmap(mThumb, left, top, right, bottom);
         canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats So Nice Of You. Thanks Buddy.