# Android - customised progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, customization

Does anyone have a idea how to do this kind progress bar?
[image]

Comment: Can't say it will help 100% but it's worth Seeing this [example](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2011/11/android-sdk-custom-slider-bar-seekbar/) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sure there is a way, try searching through the Android SDK source code at the progress bar and just pull the code from there and reference new drawables etc

Comment: You may try this by seekbar, or may create customized processbar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175018/custom-progressbar-with-multi-color

Comment: Great idea with seekbar, will try with it.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to customize the progress bar.

A good tutorial for this task is available in web. [Check this link](http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/04/android-custom-progressbar-with-rounded-corners/)

I hope it may help you.

Comment: ProgressBar is not tough, but much worse is small circle with percent inside.