# How to add two colors in progress bar in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am trying to add two colors in progress bar. in my project there is a button called "increase". When I press increase and holds it then the progress bar increases with yellow color, now what I am trying is that when I release "increase" button the progress bar should add a small bar with green color.

My problem is that when I release the button then whole progress bar is getting filled by green color instead of yellow color till I hold the button and a small bar at releasing the button.

I am attaching the screenshot.

> [image]

below is the code snippet

```
if (i == 0) {
   progressBar1.setProgress(progressBar1.getProgress() + 10);
   progressBar1.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
     R.drawable.progress_layer));
   i = 1;
  } else {
   progressBar1.setProgress(progressBar1.getProgress() + 1);
   progressBar1.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
     R.drawable.progress_layer_normal));
  }
```

Here i is 0 by default when I tap and holds the button progress bar increase with yellow color. now when I release the button i becomes 1 and green color bar should be added to the progress bar. but the whole progress bar becomes green.

[image]

Comment: I would love to see a progressbar like in Windows 7, the sparkling green one...!!!

Comment: i advice you to checkout [This][1] ..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226333/android-customised-progressbar

Comment: what "small bar with green color" do you mean? can you be more dpecific???

Comment: @pskink that means when the drawable in else condition is set then the whole progressbar will become green and i want to appear that green color after yellow color

Comment: @rahul still not clear: do you want secondary progresss or what?

Comment: when I tap and holds the button "increase" then the progress bar is increasing with yellow color, and when I release the "increase" button then a green bar should append to yellow color. its similar to instagram video recording functionality, in instagram when you holds the record button then a progress bar increases and when you release the button a red colored bar appends.

Comment: You want `|--yellow--|-red-|--gray--|`?

Comment: I want when holding button |------yellow--------|
when released |green|
again holding |---yellow---|
again released |green|
and finally it will look like
|----yellow----|green|----yellow----|green|

Comment: Ok, I have attached the image. this is what I want to do with progress bar

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to achieve that with the standard ProgressBar.
You should consider creating the custom view from scratch.
You can start [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)