# How to create a progressbar with sections?

Tags: android, progress-bar, sections

I would like to have a progress bar that is divided clearly visible sections. For examplee, a user has to go through seven steps to complete a registration process. I want the progress bar to be divided into seven equally large sections with a clear visible divider between each. Once the user has completed a step, the color of that section changes, just like a normal progress bar.

Am I forced to create a bunch of Views dynamically from code to accomplish this, or are there easier (and better) solutions out there?

Comment: You can try different background images for each progressbar.

Comment: @user1323245 you can display progress bar with no of colors as process is being gone forward.but i don't think u can divided it into sections.

Answer (score 0):

whenever your first section complete with filled all data then just set your progress bar with particular value like if your have four section in your activity then set progress bar value 25%. then move to second section and again do same process.

Comment: That's the normal way of dealing with a progress bar. It's not what I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you might get using a (non programmatic) approach is answered here. [Custom ProgressBar With Multi Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175018/custom-progressbar-with-multi-color)  Hope it helps.